# PHP: String in json parse

Tags: php, json, string, parsing, foreach

I am trying to parse a json. I am running this in a foreach loop and if I do the following it works:

```
$places = array('restaurant', 'store', 'etc')
    foreach ($this->placesCachingTypes as $places) {
      $places_location_lat = $json_decoded->json[0]->restaurant[0]->geometry->location->lat;
      $places_location_lng = $json_decoded->json[0]->restaurant[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    }
```

However, when I do the following, i.e. I change restaurant to $places (I need to do this since I have an array of different places and I want to parse all of them in a foreach loop) it doesn't work.

```
foreach ($this->placesCachingTypes as $places) {
  $places_location_lat = $json_decoded->json[0]->$places[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  $places_location_lng = $json_decoded->json[0]->$places[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Solution is changing $places to {$places}[0]

The $places array contains keywords, such as restaurant or store. So the [0] is referring to the first one in the json which is why it's needed.

Comment: removing the dollar sign?

Comment: Have you tried `->{$places}[0]`?

Comment: Why do you call this "parsing a json"? That's what `json_decode()` does. Everything using the result of that is just working with arrays and objects, it's not JSON any more.

Comment: Ultimaters answer worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have this in the first loop:

```
json[0]->restaurant[0]
json[0]->$restaurant[0]
```

But then in the next you have:

```
json[0]->$places[0]
json[0]->$places[0]
```

Perhaps you are parsing the JSON incorrectly and it should be:

```
foreach ($this->placesCachingTypes as $places) {
  $places_location_lat = $json_decoded->json[0]->places[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  $places_location_lng = $json_decoded->json[0]->places[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

And then in the first loop, you should do a similar edit to get rid of `$restaurant[0]`:

```
foreach ($this->placesCachingTypes as $places) {
  $places_location_lat = $json_decoded->json[0]->restaurant[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  $places_location_lng = $json_decoded->json[0]->restaurant[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Then again, unclear on what value `$places` has when you loop via `foreach ($this->placesCachingTypes as $places) {`. It does’t make sense what you would be looping through with the value of `$places`. And perhaps assigning that `$places` in the loop object of `$json_decoded->json[0]->` is the source of your issues? Need more info from you to confirm this.